# How to make the button ID a variable to use in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, button

I am trying to set the ID as a variable, how can i?

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    $i = 1;
    $testvar[$i] = ("NUMBER" + $i);
?>
<input type="button" id="<?php echo($testvar[$i]); ?>"/>
<script>
    var btn['<?php echo($i); ?>'] = document.getElementById("<?php echo($testvar[$i]); ?>");
    btn.onclick = CreateButton;
    function CreateButton(){
    <?php
        $counter++;
        while ($i < $counter){
            i++;
            echo("<input type='button' id='<?php echo($testvar[$i]); ?>'/>");
        }        
    ?>
};
</script>
```

The ID is not being reconigzed as a variable

Comment: How do you know that it is not being recognized? If there are errors coming up, it would be helpful to see these. If the resulting HTML does not containt proper ID, it could still be helpful to see the HTML.

Comment: which variable exactly (spell it out case sensitive) is ID. i dont' see variable named ID.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `$` to one of our variables:

```
<?php
    $counter++;
    while ($i < $counter){
        $i++; //Missing $
        echo("<input type='button' id='<?php echo($testvar[$i]); ?>'/>");
    }        
?>
```

And as a sidenote, your question is really unclear. You should describe better what is not working.